# (JSP) What does ${errorString} do? and how does it work?

Tags: jsp

In one jsp file, I saw the following code.

`<p style="color:red;"> ${errorString} </p>`

As far as I know ${ } is a JSP EL.   I want to know how errorString works. I looked through code, and I can't find how this value is returned. (Is this an implicit EL object?)
By intuition, it looks like something that shows an error message.

**How does this `${errorString}` work? and what does it do?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose for example, you have `servlet` class,and you need to  show some `message` after redirecting to any `Jsp` page: i.e

```
 request.setAttribute("errorString", "Invalid user ");//we set attribute with some message.
```

And to `display` above message in jsp page we use this : `${errorString}`

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) for more detail.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I coudn't find 'request.setAttribute' for errorString  anywhere in the code. So I thought it was a new JSP grammar or a  new implicit object.  Maybe that wasn't a complete code.